# Ahk Script to find in the current folder a file or a folder with the latest change?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I often save files from Chrome to the Downloads folder or My Documents folder.
You have to look for these files later in the folder. Tell me whether it is possible to somehow make it more convenient using the ahk script. By pressing F3 for example, the last file or folder in the current folder is highlighted. How to implement it. Please help me, I'm a new

Answer (score 1):

```
F3::
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    File := "" ; empty variable
    Time := ""
    Loop, Files, %A_MyDocuments%\Downloads\*.*, DF ; include files and folders
    {
        If (A_LoopFileTimeModified >= Time)
        {
            Time := A_LoopFileTimeModified        ; the time the file/folder was last modified
            File := A_LoopFileFullPath            ; the path and name of the file/folder currently retrieved
        }
    }
    ; MsgBox, Last modified file in %A_MyDocuments%\Downloads is`n`n"%File%"
    IfWinNotExist Downloads ahk_class CabinetWClass
        Run % "explorer.exe /select," . File      ; open containing folder and highlight this file/folder
    else
    {
        SplitPath, File, name
        MsgBox, Last modified file = "%name%"
        WinActivate, Downloads ahk_class CabinetWClass
        WinWaitActive, Downloads ahk_class CabinetWClass
        ; SelectExplorerItem(name) ; or:
        SendInput, %name%
    }
    return

SelectExplorerItem(ItemName) { ; selects the specified item in the active explorer window, if present
   ; SelectItem -> msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774047(v=vs.85).aspx
   Window := ""
   Static Shell := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")
   For Window In Shell.Windows
    try  IfWinActive, % "ahk_id " window.HWND
         If (Item := Window.Document.Folder.ParseName(ItemName))
            Window.Document.SelectItem(Item, 29)
   Return (Item ? True : False)
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm

Comment: Works great thanks! And how to make it open not in a new explorer window, but in the current window, if it is open?

Comment: Added a function to select the file in the current window, if it is open.

Comment: I tried, the code with the new function. Does not work . By F3 opens just a explorer. Here's a video https://cloud.mail.ru/public/51Ds/UMXwjNqah

Comment: Replace "Downloads" with the exact title of the explorer window as shown in Window Spy. Start Window Spy from the script's tray menu or the Start menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second version does not work at all. I also changed the downloads, it did not help. Here's a video https://cloud.mail.ru/public/FGcm/XgNHw8A5z

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. Opens Just a explorer .When the first version of your code worked. Where just in the downloads folder to find. There, in order for me to work, I registered the full path C:\Users\Reifwp\Downloads everywhere. And your subsequent versions of codes, new versions, none of them worked, unfortunately, even if I changed all the ways to C:\Users\Reifwp\Downloads

Comment: https://www.upload.ee/download/9591907/5fca5a5ca08114f2cd37/1902.ahk If you have time. Take a look.This code always works and opens only a folder in any folder.
 C:\Users\reiwp\Downloads and shows the file correctly

Comment: Added `SetTitleMatchMode, 2`. Try it this way or try replacing `Downloads` with `C:\Users\reiwp\Downloads`in the commands IfWinNotExist, WinActivate and WinWaitActive.

Comment: bro, so how to do. That there was a file in the current folder. Not in downloads. And in the folder in which I am now. What will be the code? I think you need to somehow use Folderlpath: = ActiveTitle.